# How to combine for loop through rows and if statement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I know it might be really basic, but I can't seem to get it right...
I have a dataframe with 4 columns indexed by a timestamp.
I would like to loop through each row and, if a value of a certain row is beyond limits, print both the timestamp, column name and value.
How do I iterate within applying the filter?

Values are all floats and have been trying with iterrows and iteritems.

```
inf_value = -5
sup_value = 200

for index, row in df.iterrows():
   if row > sup_value:
      print(index, df.column, value)
   if row < inf_value:
      print(index, df.column, value)
```

I would expect it to print the timestamp followed by the column name and value such as:
05/08/2019 Column1 205.5

Any help?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: what do you mean by the value of certain row??

Comment: Do you mean "if any of the values in the row" are outside the given limits?

Comment: Please paste in your question the output of "df.head(5)". We will have a better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to check if any of the values are outside the given limits, and if so, print the indices (row and column) of those values.

To do so, you need to compare each value to the limits, not a row:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for column, value in row.items():
        if value > sup_value:
            print(index, column, value)
        if value < inf_value:
            print(index, column, value)
```

Comment: Great, thanks for your help! You solved my problem.
Just to correct you a minor thing:

    print(index, column, row[column])

Comment: You're right, I've edited to call for `value` by iterating over `row.items()` (similar logic to what we did with rows)